# Get chaincode caller ID from the function InvokeChaincode() in Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK

Tags: node.js, go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Let's suppose the following network architecture:

**A** -> **Chaincode1** -> **fabcar**

**A** is the application, **Chaincode1** is a chaincode in Go and **fabcar** is a chaincode in Nodejs.
They are on the same channel: "mychannel".

When is performed the operation `APIstub.InvokeChaincode` from the **Chaincode1** such as `APIstub.InvokeChaincode("fabcar", chainCodeArgs, "mychannel")`, is there a possibility for the chaincode **fabcar** (the chaincode called) to get the **id** of the the caller chaincode?

The `getCreator()` method in the **fabcar** chaincode just returns the caller organization; but the information needed is *the chaincode id* or some info only connected to the **Chaincode1**.

---

**UPDATE**

I tryed the `getSignedProposal()` method as written in the official documentation of hyperledger: https://fabric-shim.github.io/ChaincodeStub.html#getSignedProposal__anchor

The `getSignedProposal()` method returns a fully decoded object of the signed transaction proposal of type `SignedProposal`.
The `SignedProposal` object represents the request object sent by the client application to the chaincode.

Executing the following code:

```
const proposal = stub.getSignedProposal();
console.log("signed proposal: ", proposal);
```

the result is the following:

```
signed proposal:  { signature: <Buffer 30 45 02 21 00 c3 a7 91 4c 74 f9 c2 97 04 fc 84 91 6a 71 2d 69 ad 0e a9 22 f2 ed 53 a3 66 97 56 17 d7 d7 3a e6 02 20 13 26 8a 4f f6 3d 86 4e f9 35 ae ... >,
  proposal:
   { header: { signature_header: [Object], channel_header: [Object] },
     payload: { input: [Object], TransientMap: [Object] } } }
```

Seems really difficult to understand which is the info where is possible to retrieve the **calling chaincode ID**.
Here is the link of the doc concerning the `SignedProposal` type: https://fabric-shim.github.io/global.html#SignedProposal

Comment: People voting -1 can at least explain what is wrong with my question so I can correct? Mine seems a problem that could be interesting for all the community. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to do this because the chaincode itself does not have an identity, per se.

Comment: So there is no way to know in which way a chaincode called another one. This sounds real bad If someone wants to reply with a callback...

Comment: Theoretical you should be able extract information from SingedProposal, which in case of cc2cc just passed from one to another, hence second one can use it.

Answer (score 2):

> The `getCreator()` function in the fabcar chaincode just returns the caller organization, I want the chaincode id or some info only connected to the Chaincode1.

You can use `GetSignedProposal` method, i.e.:

```
// data elements part of a transaction proposal.
GetSignedProposal() (*pb.SignedProposal, error)
```

the `SignedProposal` contains information of the original chaincode client sent transaction proposal, in case of chaincode to chaincode invocation `SignedProposal` simply forwarded, hence you can extract information of previous chaincode.

**NOTE**: If you have complex chain of chaincodes invocations, e.g. *chaincode1* calls *chaincode2* which calls chaincode3, `SignedProposal` will contain information of *chaincode1* i.e. you won't know about *chaincode2*.

Comment: This way you can get the identity of the invoker. That's nice. But who will be the signer of the of the execution of the second chaincode?

Comment: Not following, can you explain?